# Create new user with existing data

Tags: linux, authentication

I have reinstalled fesh linux mint without formatting `/home` data.. I had some users in previous os. Now it is showing only single user log in. I can see other user's data in file system. How can i get back old user login? Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

useradd -b (path) (username)

refer this [link](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)